# How to disable the Touchable Opacity for some specific item that comes from API in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, components

I have an API and I need to set the **Touchable Opacity** separately
for each item. I have done it already. but now I need to disable some
**Touchable Opacity**. Like what I am trying to do is if **Status** and **Check** in API both are **True** then the User can move to next and the color of it is red.

Screen by pressing on that **touchable opacity** but if one of them is
**false** then the **touchable opacity** will be disabled and a user can't move to the next screen and the color of it will be grey I don't know how to do it because I am very new in this kind of functionality in React-native I read different questions and answers but unfortunately that doesn't help me.

API Response

```
const results = [
   {
            Id: "IySO9wUrt8",
            Name: "Los Stand",
            Category: "Mexican",
            Status: true,
            Check: true,
        },
    {
            Id: "IySO9wUrt8",
            Name: "Los Stand 2",
            Category: "Burger",
            Status: true,
            Check: true,
        },
     {
            Id: "IySO9wUrt8",
            Name: "Los Stand 3",
            Category: "BBq",
            Status: true,
            Check: true,
        },
      ];
```

My full code

**App.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  StyleSheet,
  FlatList,
  SafeAreaView,
} from 'react-native';
import { Card, TextInput, RadioButton } from 'react-native-paper';

const results = [
  {
    Id: 'IySO9wUrt8',
    Name: 'Los Stand',
    Category: 'Mexican',
    Status: true,
     Check: true,
  },
  {
    Id: 'IySO9wUrt8',
    Name: 'Los Stand 2',
    Category: 'Burger',
    Status: true,
     Check: true,
  },
  {
    Id: 'IySO9wUrt8',
    Name: 'Los Stand 3',
    Category: 'BBq',
    Status: true,
     Check: true,
  },
];

export default function App() {

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => {

    return (
      <>
       <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() =>
          navigation.navigate('NextScreen', {
            name: item.Name,
            phone: item.Phone,
          })
        }>
        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: 'column',
            marginHorizontal: 10,
            marginVertical: 10,
            padding: 5,
            backgroundColor: 'grey',
            borderRadius: 15,
          }}>
          
          <View
            style={{
              flexDirection: 'column',
              alignSelf: 'flex-start',
              marginTop: 10,
              marginBottom: 10,
            }}>
            <Text
              style={{
                fontSize: 15,
                fontWeight: '900',
                color: '#424242',
              }}>
              {item.Name}
            </Text>
            <Text>{item.Phone}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
   
      </>
    );
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        style={styles.container}
        data={results}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 2,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
});
```

**AssetExample.js**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Image } from 'react-native';

export default function AssetExample() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
        Local files and assets can be imported by dragging and dropping them into the editor
      </Text>
      <Image style={styles.logo} source={require('../assets/snack-icon.png')} />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: 24,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    marginTop: 0,
    fontSize: 14,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  logo: {
    height: 128,
    width: 128,
  }
});
```

You can edit code in Expo Snack

[My Expo code for live editing](https://snack.expo.dev/@muhammadabdullahrishi/disable-touchable-for-item)

Comment: Please don't tag spam. Also please make more effort to format your question properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TouchableOpacity` has a `disabled` property, so you should use it. It will prevent `onPress` from executing and navigating the user.

As for the styling, you can check the style using the same login.

```
<TouchableOpacity disabled={!result.Status || !result.Check} style={{ background: (!result.Status || !result.Check) ? 'grey' : 'red' }}>
```